# Using offline map provider (OpenStreetMap or other free map) in Blazor

Tags: html, asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor, asp.net-core-3.1

My web app will be on intranet and I cannot use any online map provider.
Is there any offline map provider to work with Blazor or how to setup any map provider to use it offline for specific region/country?
I need only simple functionalities for now (showing a mark on the map, rezising/moving the map).

Answer (score 3):

For maps to be offline, you will need them to be downloaded in browser - or as your app will be internal, you can have these downloaded on the server and the clients can use that as map tile source.

There are many options you can use with openstreetmap to download in a SQLite database.

One option I found is to use leaflet with offline capability, see here: https://github.com/tbicr/OfflineMap/tree/master/leaflet_idb_sql_site

From a demo, you can see the map tiles are stored in the browser db as base64:
[image]

Another option [(here)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/48879)